# Count max score of hex tile combinations (board game)

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I was trying to implement scoring calculation for a board game as a hobby. The problem can be reduced to the following simplified form:

- there's a hex grid: some tiles are filled, others are not
- score is given for number of tiles filled in a straight line (score by length: {1:2, 2:5, 3:9, 4:13}, note that there's no score for length 5+)
- lines may be adjacent (e.g. if you have a line of length 6 it still counts as line of length 4 + 2 giving 18 score total)
- a filled tile can only be counted once (can belong only to one counted line)
- we may assume that all filled tiles are connected
- the resulting score is the maximum score across all possible combinations of the filled tiles

Example (different colors stand for groups of tiles counted together, top is the total score; white tiles are not filled):

```
  - A -
 - A B -
- A - B
 A C C B
A=13, B=9, C=5, total=27

  - A -
 - A B -
- A - B
 C C C B
A=B=C=9, total=27

  - A -
 - A C -
- A - B
 A D B E
A=13, B=5, C=D=E=2, total=24
```

P.S. there's also a more generic rule in that game that doesn't restrict the filled tiles to form a straight line. Maybe there are some thoughts on it too.

I have thought about it for quite a while, it turned out to be harder than I initially thought. Basically I can't come up with any assumptions that may reduce the computational complexity significanly enough.

One obvious simplification is that if we are to count score of a single straight line, the greedy algorithm will always give the max score for it (take as many 4's as possible, then 3's and so on). But it doesn't really help a lot in general situation.

Another simple improvement is not to count particular combinations at all if current maximum yields more that theoretical maximum of the combination.

One could probably assume that greedy path is the way to go always, but there are cases when it doesn't work, e.g.:

```
  - A B C
 - A B C
- - B -
 D B E -
A=5, B=13, C=5, D=E=2, total=27

  - A A A
 - B B B
- - D -
 C C C -
A=B=C=9, D=2, total=29
```

Picking the line of 4 tiles with remainders here will yield less score than picking 3x3+1.

So I can only end up with a brute force algo, which runs insanely slow on large tile groups and even gives a stack overflow sometimes. I.e. for N tiles enumerate all combinations of 4 tiles forming a line (N choose 4 = binomial = n!/(k!*(n-k)!)), for each of them recursively do the same with remainder. If there are no 4's, then go for 3's and so on until you reach 1's, which yield NumberOfOnes*2 score. Pick max of all combinations.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Doing it "recursively" doesn't sound like a bad idea, but you should cache intermediary results, otherwise the time complexity will blow up exponentially.

Comment: In addition to caching, I suggest "splitting" the grid into connected components; for instance if you have the grid https://i.stack.imgur.com/T68ar.png then you can immediately split it into the two grids https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqbf7.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvbnn.png and add the two subscores. This will quickly reduce the size of the grids and reduce the number of duplicated computations. You should do this splitting at every step of the recursion, whenever possible (and looking at only one player at a time)

Comment: @Stef, actually I already do both. The description in question is simplified version that I am to solve after mapping connections and finding isolated regions. But probably I can cache better, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you're considering each cell in order from top to bottom, left to right, and deciding how to count it.  It'll either be nothing new or a row of some length pointing to the right, down-left, or down-right.  It can't point in the other directions, because then it would have been decided earlier.

At any point, you can only affect cells in the current row and the next 3 rows, and you will never have to look at the rows above again. The pattern of cells that are already "used" in these 4 rows, along with the current accumulated score, represent your complete state.

Not all patterns of used cells are possible, because any used cell in rows 2-4 need to be connected by a line to a cell in the top row.  A configuration can be represented as a combination of down-left length and down-right length for each top-row cell.  There are 17 viable combinations for each top row cell.

A reasonable way to solve your problem is to proceed from top-left to bottom-right.  You will maintain an array that provides the best attainable score for every possible configuration of used cells in the current 4 rows.  For each cell, you have to calculate the new array from the previous one in O(possible_configurations) time.

To store one of these configuration arrays, you'll need 17<sup>row_length</sup> slots.  That makes this algorithm practical for row lengths up to 6 or 7.

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll definitely try it. Grid size can easily exceed 7 in that game, but many tiles are going to be blank generally.